# Check palindrome without using string functions with condition

Tags: sql, string

I have a table `EmployeeTable`.
If I want only that records where `employeename` have character of 1 to 5 
will be palindrome and there also condition like total  character is more then 10 then 4 to 8 if character less then 7 then 2 to 5 and if character less then 5 then all char will be checked and there that are palindrome then only display.

```
Examples :- neen will be display
            neetan not selected
            kiratitamara will be selected
```

I try this something on string function like FOR first case like name less then 5 character long

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(EmployeeName,1,5),* from EmaployeeTable where 
          REVERSE (SUBSTRING(EmployeeName,1,5))=SUBSTRING(EmployeeName,1,5)
```

**I want to do that without string functions**,
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: May I ask you why you dont want to use string functions?

Comment: You want to do string manipulations without using string functions?  Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What do you mean with string function? Lenght(varchar2) may also be considered a string function because it receives a string as parameter! You can't check conditions on strings if you don't use string functions.

Comment: i don't want to use like string reverse and substring function so that's why i told you that i don't want to use string build in function.

Comment: i used sql server 2012 r2 DBMS

Answer (score 1):

You need at least `SUBSTRING()`, I have a solution like this:
(*In SQL Server*)

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(max) = 'abcba'

;WITH CTE (cNo, cChar) AS (
    SELECT 1, SUBSTRING(@txt, 1, 1) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cNo + 1, SUBSTRING(@txt, cNo + 1, 1) 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE SUBSTRING(@txt, cNo + 1, 1) <> ''
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cNo DESC) as cRevNo
    FROM CTE t1 CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT Max(cNo) AS strLength FROM CTE) t2) dt
WHERE
    dt.cNo <= dt.strLength / 2
    AND
    dt.cChar <> (SELECT dti.cChar FROM CTE dti WHERE dti.cNo = cRevNo)
```

The result will shows the count of differences and `0` means no differences.

> **Note :**
>   Current solution is *Non-Case-Sensitive* for change it to a *Case-Sensitive* you need to check the strings in a case-sensitive collation like `Latin1_General_BIN`

You can use this solution as a SVF or something like that.

Comment: i don't want to use Even Substring.

Answer (score 0):

I dont realy understand why you dont want to use string functions in your query, but here is one solution. Compute everything beforehand:

Add Column:

```
 ALTER TABLE EmployeeTable
            ADD SubString AS 
            SUBSTRING(EmployeeName,
               (
               CASE WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>10 
               THEN 4
               WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>7
               THEN 2
               ELSE 1 END
               )
            ,
            (
               CASE WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>10 
               THEN 8
               WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>7
               THEN 5
               ELSE 5 END
               )
             PERSISTED
        GO

            ALTER TABLE EmployeeTable
            ADD Palindrome AS 
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(EmployeeName,
               (
               CASE WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>10 
               THEN 4
               WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>7
               THEN 2
               ELSE 1 END
               )
            ,
            (
               CASE WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>10 
               THEN 8
               WHEN LEN(EmployeeName)>7
               THEN 5
               ELSE 5 END
               )) PERSISTED
        GO
```

Then your query will looks like:

```
    SELECT * from EmaployeeTable 
    where Palindrome = SubString
```

BUT!
This is not a good idea. Please tell us, why you dont want to use string functios.

Comment: i know that the string function is option but that is build in function and i already able to get the output using that function like string reverse and sub-string but i want to do that without string function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it building a list of palindrome words using a recursive query that generates palindrome words till a length o n characters and then selects employees with the name matching a palindrome word. This may be a really inefficient way, but it does the trick

This is a [sample query for Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb), PostgreSQL should support this feature as well with little differences on syntax. I don't know about other RDBMS.

```
with EmployeeTable AS (
    SELECT 'ADA' AS employeename
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'IDA' AS employeename
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JACK' AS employeename
    FROM DUAL
  ), letters as (
    select chr(ascii('A') + rownum - 1) as letter
    from dual
    connect by ascii('A') + rownum - 1 <= ascii('Z')
  ), palindromes(word, len ) as (
    SELECT WORD, LEN
    FROM (
        select CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(100)) as word, 0 as len
        from DUAL
        union all
        select letter as word, 1 as len
        from letters
      )
    union all
    select l.letter||p.word||l.letter AS WORD, len + 1 AS LEN
    from palindromes p
      cross join letters l
    where len <= 4
  )
  SEARCH BREADTH FIRST BY word SET order1
  CYCLE word SET is_cycle TO 'Y' DEFAULT 'N'
select *
from EmployeeTable
WHERE employeename IN (
    SELECT WORD
    FROM palindromes
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cPalindrome VARCHAR(100) = 'SUBI NO ONIBUS'

SET @cPalindrome = REPLACE(@cPalindrome, ' ', '')
;WITH tPalindromo (iNo) AS (
    SELECT 1
     WHERE SUBSTRING(@cPalindrome, 1, 1) = SUBSTRING(@cPalindrome, LEN(@cPalindrome), 1) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT iNo + 1
      FROM tPalindromo
     WHERE SUBSTRING(@cPalindrome, iNo + 1, 1) = SUBSTRING(@cPalindrome, LEN(@cPalindrome) - iNo, 1) 
       AND LEN(@cPalindrome) > iNo
)

SELECT IIF(MAX(iNo) = LEN(@cPalindrome), 'PALINDROME', 'NOT PALINDROME')
  FROM tPalindromo
```